# Does x-wing support more than 2 players

Tags: star-wars-x-wing

Can you play x-wing with more than 2 people?

If so, what all do I need to achieve more than 2 players?

Free for all? Teams?

Answer (score 13):

My games club plays *furballs*. Each player gets 1 ship to a maximum point limit agreed beforehand (we usually pick 30 points).

Each player has a spawn point. Every time a player is destroyed, they respawn. The player who destroyed that ship gains a point. The player who was destroyed loses a point. Play continues until a player reaches a score limit (we usually play to +5) or a time limit is reached (we usually play for an hour for 6 players, adding 10 minutes for each extra player).

Variation on furballs: *bounty hunting*. Randomly allocate each player a bounty player. Keep this knowledge secret. If you destroy your bounty, gain +2 to your score, instead of the usual +1

Answer (score 11):

On page 20 of the [core rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/37/64/376454fc-e2b9-4a9b-8d99-300f104cefac/swx01_xwingcorerulebook_lowres.pdf) there are rules to play as two teams of arbitrary size - basically, each team has a squad of ships which are assigned to players however you like, then teams may discuss strategy as much as they like but each player makes the decisions for their particular ships.

Or you could play that each team strategises, plans and makes their moves together, such as was done when Seth Green, Clare Grant and Mike Lamond joined Wil Wheaton on [the X-Wing episode of TableTop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mxPFHBCfuU).

A google search suggests that some people have tried playing 3-player free-for-alls, but unless you score by damage dealt then you often have a scenario where one player avoids the other two until one is eliminated, then swoops in to deal with the remains of the other.

Answer (score 3):

[Mission 12: Bounty Hunt](http://xwing-miniatures.wikia.com/wiki/Mission_12:_Bounty_Hunt), which can be found in the IG-2000 Expansion Pack, is a scenario for 3 players. I've tried it both as Han Solo vs. Boba Fett vs. IG-88B and as three 100-point squads with a designated wing leader. Either way, it's always gone smoothly as a way for 3 people to play a single game of X-Wing.